# Is there a way to use MATLAB function handles in MEX files without the mexCallMATLAB function

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm currently writing a MEX file in C to speed up MATLAB code that heavily relies on function handles. Unfortunately, my MEX file runs slower than it should because I have to to use `mexCallMATLAB`  to evaluate the handles in MATLAB (as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/274319)).

Most of the function handles are simple inline functions that take uniform random numbers and generate random variables. A typical example is:

```
f = @(u) exp(norminv(u))
```

Even as the function handles use built-in MATLAB functions, my code has to allow users to use their own function handles, which prevents me from hard coding the functions into a MEX file.

Ideally I would like to provide the MEX file with a way to evaluate this function handle without having to use the `mexCallMATLAB` function everytime. Does anyone have any idea on how such a thing can be done? I'm open to any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that is the only way.  A way to help with the speed would be to only call it once - send it a vector of the values that will be needed and use the returned vector in your mex file.

Comment: Hmm I thought of this but it will not work for this exact situation. Do you think it would be possible to have MATLAB generate C code from the function handles and somehow include / reference those within the MEX file?

Comment: You can do that via the matlab compiler.  I've never used it (don't own it), but it seems like it would help with what you need - http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1622.html